# Triangle in descending output

Tags: java, loops

Why is it the output enters new line after 3? like this:

> 9
>
> 8 7
>
> 6 5 4
>
> 3
>
> 2 1

any number i input it always enters a new line after 3. My target output should be like this when i input 9:

> 9
>
> 8 7
>
> 6 5 4
>
> 3 2 1 0

Will you please clarify to me why is it enters a new line after 3?

```
public class TriangleWithInput {

/**
 * @param args
 */
@SuppressWarnings("resource")
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
    int input = sc.nextInt();

    while (input >= 0) {
        int c = 1;
        while ( c <= input) {
            int r = 1;
            while (r <= c) {
                System.out.print(input + " ");
                input--;
                r++;
            }
            System.out.println();
            c++;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Try adding: `System.out.println("r: " + r + " c:" + " input:" + input);` in your inner while loop and you can debug the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seem to have one too many nested loops. You are getting a new line because of the test `c <= input`; when `input` reaches 3 and `c >= 3`, you do a line break and reset `c` to 1.

I'd write your loops like this:

```
for (int r = 1; input >= 0; ++r) {
    for (int c = 1; c <= r && input >= 0; ++c, --input) {
        System.out.print(input + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: why is it your variable `r` in the first loop has no condition?

Comment: @JaGb - Because you don't care how many lines of output it takes. (`r` is the number of rows of output.) The terminating condition is that `input` goes below 0.

Comment: @Tedd Hopp - You're right, I should have ignored how many lines of output it will take. I was thinking of what condition should i use with the first loop, I knew it where's my error is while having this trial and error during coding. Thanks, it helped me a lot. I'll read and understand your code. I really wanted to learn programming :)